# run ubuntu command in python

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have an ubuntu machine and I install software called FSL that does segmentation for MRI images, I have around 1000 images so I need to repeat these line of codes around 1000 times

```
run_first_all -d -i InputImages/Autism/04.nii.gz -s L_Puta,R_Puta,BrStem -o OutputImage/Autism/Puta/04
run_first_all -d -i InputImages/Autism/04.nii.gz -s L_Caud,R_Caud,BrStem -o OutputImage/Autism/Caud/04
run_first_all -d -i InputImages/Autism/04.nii.gz -s L_Accu,R_Accu,BrStem -o OutputImage/Autism/Accu/04
run_first_all -d -i InputImages/Autism/04.nii.gz -s L_Pall,R_Pall,BrStem -o OutputImage/Autism/Pall/04
run_first_all -d -i InputImages/Autism/04.nii.gz -s L_Hipp,R_Hipp,BrStem -o OutputImage/Autism/Hipp/04
run_first_all -d -i InputImages/Autism/04.nii.gz -s L_Amyg,R_Amyg,BrStem -o OutputImage/Autism/Amyg/04
run_first_all -d -i InputImages/Autism/04.nii.gz -s L_Thal,R_Thal,BrStem -o OutputImage/Autism/Thal/04
```

each time I change the number of the image for example here the image number is 04 so in the next iteration it will be 05
how could I use the power of python to automate that?

Comment: This is run in bash and the only change replacing `04` for `05` in the command? It might be easier to script it in bash rather than python

Comment: How are the files beyond 100 named? From`04` it looks like they're zero padded to 2 digits, are the rest padded at all?

Answer (score 1):

If these are all run as bash commands and there is no python API to the software I would use bash for the scripting as well. Something like

```
function process {
    # Pad the number to at least 2 digits
    printf -v num "%02d" $0
    source="InputImages/Autism/$num.nii.gz"
    output="OutputImage/Autism/"
    run_first_all -d -i $source -s L_Puta,R_Puta,BrStem -o $output/Puta/$num
    run_first_all -d -i $source -s L_Caud,R_Caud,BrStem -o $output/Caud/$num
    run_first_all -d -i $source -s L_Accu,R_Accu,BrStem -o $output/Accu/$num
    run_first_all -d -i $source -s L_Pall,R_Pall,BrStem -o $output/Pall/$num
    run_first_all -d -i $source -s L_Hipp,R_Hipp,BrStem -o $output/Hipp/$num
    run_first_all -d -i $source -s L_Amyg,R_Amyg,BrStem -o $output/Amyg/$num
    run_first_all -d -i $source -s L_Thal,R_Thal,BrStem -o $output/Thal/$num
}

# Loop over the number of files you have, processing each in turn
for i in {0..1000}; do
    process i
done
```

If this processing can be done concurrently (eg if each process only uses a single thread), you could look into tools like `parallel` but this should be enough to save you having to run everything manually.